# Passing information to jqModal

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqmodal

I'm using jqModal inside a Django application.  What I would like to do is have a bunch of different links each of which passes a parameter to jqModal to have it call a different ajax url based on the parameter.  For example, depending on the ID of what is click on, I want to do something like:

```
$('#popup').jqm({ajax: '/myapp/objects/' + id, trigger: 'div.modaltrigger'});
```

Where id is the id of whatever I've clicked on.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: What are you asking, exactly? If you are simply asking if it is possible, then I would say it is possible. If that code is executed more than once, it is probable you will see more than one modal dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Use [data attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) of the triggering elements to store your URLs:

```
<div class="modaltrigger" data-ajax-url="/myapp/objects/108"...
```

Then use jqModal in the following way:

```
$('#popup').jqm({ajax: '@data-ajax-url', trigger: 'div.modaltrigger'});
```

Answer (score 2):

You said you want to change the url depending on ID, so I assume your links look like this

```
<div id="obj1" class="modaltrigger">foo</div>
<div id="obj2" class="modaltrigger">bar</div>
```

And you want jqModal to call urls like this

```
/myapp/objects/obj1
/myapp/objects/obj2
```

Then this code should work

```
//must run before first ajax call is made
$('div.modaltrigger').each(function(i, ele) {
    ele.title = '/myapp/objects/'+this.id;
});

$('#popup').jqm({
    ajax: '@title',
    trigger: 'div.modaltrigger'
});
```

Comment: thank you i was facing this problem and used your solution and it is working nicely